# Showing that $x$ is algebraically independent in $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am studying Noether's normalization lemma, and I couldn't find a way to prove that

> $\bar{x}$ is algebraically independent in $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$.

Can anyone give me a hint or help me please?

Comment: You mean, transcendental over $k$?

Comment: Algebraic independence usually refers to a family, not to a single element. Do you mean transcendental ? (The family $\{a\}$ is algebraically independent over $k$ iff $a$ is transcendental over $k$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(\bar x)=0$, where $f$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $k$, then $f(x)\in(xy-1)$, so $f(x)=(xy-1)g(x,y)$. Now take $y=1/x$ and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** By the very definition, $k[x,y]/(xy-1) \simeq k[x,x^{-1}]$.